# How to create Hello World web application in intellij idea?

Tags: jakarta-ee, intellij-idea

I am new in java web application and for the first time I want create and run Hello World web based application and deploy it on Tommcat in intelliJ  idea I search a lot in the Google and read this document  :

https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/java-ee.html

But I can't run create Hello World project  .Can anyone one help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this links is helpfull [Java webapp](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/developing-a-java-ee-application.html).
It's a guide how to make a HelloWorld app in intelliJ. The guide is with a GlassFish server but Tomcat should work to.